# Javascript Control many types with "typeof" without "if"

Tags: javascript, loops, object, if-statement, typeof

I was wondering if there is an alternative to the classic.

```
if (typeof firstPost === 'object' && typeof firstPost.active === 'boolean' && typeof firstPost.message === 'string' && typeof firstPost.maxHeight)
```

So as to avoid writing more code, maybe looping object.

Comment: Writing less code should never be the goal. Writing clean, clear, maintainable and testable code should be the goal.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this:

if this is user input

```
var firstPost = {
    active    : true,
    message   : "hello",
    maxHeight : 20
}
```

then:

```
var checks = {
    active    : 'boolean',
    message   : 'string',
    maxHeight : 'number'
}

try {
    for(var key in checks) {
        if(typeof firstPost[key] != checks[key]) {
            throw new Error(key + " is not " + checks[key]);
        }
    }
}catch(e) {
    alert(e.toString());
}
```

this is not bytesless, but it's more clean. (and it checks also if all keys are defined)

EDIT: 
There is no way more compact. However you can declare some function in another place and call it.

```
function checkObject(obj,checks) {
    for(var key in checks) {
        if(typeof obj[key] != checks[key]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and simply

```
checkObject(firstPost,{
    active    : 'boolean',
    message   : 'string',
    maxHeight : 'number'
});
```

You can elaborate another return type in order to specify the error.

Comment: You should either `throw` or `return false`, not both. The try-catch-clause is unnecessary and slow.

Comment: @Bergi you're right. Thank you. I was thinking some other things, and I've lost myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

If there are always the same types and you're needing this exact if more often, you could wrap it in a function. 
Otherwise your if construct is the only real possibility you have I think. Of course you could create an object with the key as fieldname and the value as the required type, but I wouldn't do that, as it won't be easiliy readable anymore.

only thing that comes to my mind that would shorten this code (a little bit), is wrapping the typeof function into something like this:

```
function is(variable, type){
  return typeof variable == type;
}
```

So you could just call it like `is(firstPost, 'object')` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Looping object or using another way will have more code than you wrote.
Of course you can use "||" method to compare in javascript or kind of "? :" if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first check can be simplified, because object instances are truthy `!!{} === true`, and you don't need to check specifically for object because you are checking if it has the properties later.

And most times you only need to know if there is data inside the object and not exactly if it is of a specific type:

```
function notUndef (aux) {
 return aux !== undefined;
}

if (firstPost && notUndef(firstPost.active) && notUdenf(firstPost.message) && notUndef(firstPost.maxHeight))
```

If you have a really long list of properties to check you can use a loop:

```
function checkHasProps (obj, properties) {
  obj || return false; 
  var hasAll = true;
  properties.forEach(function (prop) {
    if (obj[prop] === undefined) {
      hasAll = false;
    }
  });
  return hasAll;
}

if (checkHasProps(['active', 'message', 'maxHeight', (...)]));
```

And remember that `typeof [] === 'object'`, so `typeof` is not a completly reliable way to check things.